# How to fix module not callable error in the Jupyter?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I am practicing functions. I am trying to run the below reproducible code in Jupyter but fetching error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Below is the reproducible code creating the function `gbp_to_usd`:

```
def gbp_to_usd(gbp):
    usd = float(gbp) * 1.5
    return usd

gbp = input("Enter the gbp: ")
usd = gbp_to_usd(gbp)

print("The converted gbp amount in usd is: " + str(usd))
```

[image]

But when I run the same code in IDE, I do not get the error:

[image]

I tried running the same code in Python IDE and replicate the error, but to my surprise, it ran successfully. So this got me confused further. I researched online and found that a missing mathematical operator could cause this error but my function here is not missing any operator (function `gbp_to_usd` has a basic mathematical operation).

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error? why can't it call `str()` on a float variable?

Let me know

Comment: We need a [mre] -- a code sample complete enough to cause the problem when run without any changes, included in the question itself.

Comment: Consider testing in a sandbox like http://ideone.com to see if your reproducer is complete enough for others to see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have ran 164 cells before the one shown in the image. One of those cells has overwritten `print` or `str` functions with a module object since those are the only 2 functions on the line that are being called

On a fresh Python environment (or a reset Jupyter kernel), you shouldn't expect that error, and thus, that is the "fix"

Comment: This seems to me like an explanation of why the question should be closed as not providing a minimal reproducer (and otherwise "lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem", per the first bullet point in the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)), as opposed to an answer as such.